# Cannot run Airflow's KubernetesPodOperator using Default Cloud Composer Environment

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

## Overview

I just deployed a Cloud Composer environment using all defaults. I then followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator) to try a simple `KubernetesPodOperator` out. When I copy the script into my DAGs directory and let it run, I get an error involving `No SSH tunnels currently open. Were the targets able to accept an ssh-key for user...`.

## Source Code

I copy/pasted a snippet directly from the [example code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/composer/workflows/kubernetes_pod_operator.py).

```
import datetime
from airflow import models
from airflow.contrib.kubernetes import pod
from airflow.contrib.kubernetes import secret
from airflow.contrib.operators import kubernetes_pod_operator

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
with models.DAG(
        dag_id='composer_sample_kubernetes_pod',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        start_date=YESTERDAY) as dag:
    kubenetes_template_ex = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id='ex-kube-templates',
        name='ex-kube-templates',
        namespace='default',
        image='bash',
        # All parameters below are able to be templated with jinja -- cmds,
        # arguments, env_vars, and config_file. For more information visit:
        # https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#default-variables

        # Entrypoint of the container, if not specified the Docker container's
        # entrypoint is used. The cmds parameter is templated.
        cmds=['echo'],
        # DS in jinja is the execution date as YYYY-MM-DD, this docker image
        # will echo the execution date. Arguments to the entrypoint. The docker
        # image's CMD is used if this is not provided. The arguments parameter
        # is templated.
        arguments=['{{ ds }}'])
```

## Error Trace

```
*** Reading remote log from gs://[BUCKET]/logs/composer_sample_kubernetes_pod/ex-kube-templates/2019-02-25T15:46:57.225930+00:00/1.log.
[2019-02-26 15:47:08,609] {models.py:1361} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: composer_sample_kubernetes_pod.ex-kube-templates 2019-02-25T15:46:57.225930+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-02-26 15:47:08,617] {models.py:1361} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: composer_sample_kubernetes_pod.ex-kube-templates 2019-02-25T15:46:57.225930+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-02-26 15:47:08,617] {models.py:1573} INFO -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2019-02-26 15:47:08,659] {models.py:1595} INFO - Executing <Task(KubernetesPodOperator): ex-kube-templates> on 2019-02-25T15:46:57.225930+00:00
[2019-02-26 15:47:08,660] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run composer_sample_kubernetes_pod ex-kube-templates 2019-02-25T15:46:57.225930+00:00 --job_id 2 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/dag_pod_helloworld.py --cfg_path /tmp/tmp6xuy0jka']
[2019-02-26 15:47:10,302] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:10,302] {settings.py:176} INFO - setting.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800
[2019-02-26 15:47:10,672] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:10,671] {default_celery.py:80} WARNING - You have configured a result_backend of redis://airflow-redis-service:6379/0, it is highly recommended to use an alternative result_backend (i.e. a database).
[2019-02-26 15:47:10,673] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:10,673] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2019-02-26 15:47:10,750] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:10,750] {app.py:51} WARNING - Using default Composer Environment Variables. Overrides have not been applied.
[2019-02-26 15:47:10,758] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:10,758] {configuration.py:516} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2019-02-26 15:47:10,766] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:10,766] {configuration.py:516} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2019-02-26 15:47:10,875] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:10,875] {models.py:271} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/gcs/dags/dag_pod_helloworld.py
[2019-02-26 15:47:12,293] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:12,292] {cli.py:484} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: composer_sample_kubernetes_pod.ex-kube-templates 2019-02-25T15:46:57.225930+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-584cf75548-rbf7x
[2019-02-26 15:47:12,829] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:12,827] {pod_launcher.py:121} INFO - Event: ex-kube-templates-c87ea4f8 had an event of type Pending
[2019-02-26 15:47:13,836] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:13,836] {pod_launcher.py:121} INFO - Event: ex-kube-templates-c87ea4f8 had an event of type Pending
[2019-02-26 15:47:14,843] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:14,843] {pod_launcher.py:121} INFO - Event: ex-kube-templates-c87ea4f8 had an event of type Pending
[2019-02-26 15:47:15,850] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:15,850] {pod_launcher.py:121} INFO - Event: ex-kube-templates-c87ea4f8 had an event of type Pending
[2019-02-26 15:47:16,858] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:16,857] {pod_launcher.py:121} INFO - Event: ex-kube-templates-c87ea4f8 had an event of type Succeeded
[2019-02-26 15:47:16,859] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2: Subtask ex-kube-templates [2019-02-26 15:47:16,858] {pod_launcher.py:184} INFO - Event with job id ex-kube-templates-c87ea4f8 Succeeded
[2019-02-26 15:47:16,896] {models.py:1760} ERROR - (500
Reason: Internal Server Erro
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '03bf375f-a5b3-4514-9903-a17cc3a3f886', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Tue, 26 Feb 2019 15:47:16 GMT', 'Content-Length': '322'}
HTTP response body: b'{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Get https://10.142.15.217:10250/containerLogs/default/ex-kube-templates-c87ea4f8/base?follow=true\\u0026tailLines=10: No SSH tunnels currently open. Were the targets able to accept an ssh-key for user \\"gke-9d36bbaf757434bb291e\\"?","code":500}\n

Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 123, in execut
    get_logs=self.get_logs
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 90, in run_po
    return self._monitor_pod(pod, get_logs
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 102, in _monitor_po
    _preload_content=False
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 18583, in read_namespaced_pod_lo
    (data) = self.read_namespaced_pod_log_with_http_info(name, namespace, **kwargs
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 18689, in read_namespaced_pod_log_with_http_inf
    collection_formats=collection_formats
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 321, in call_ap
    _return_http_data_only, collection_formats, _preload_content, _request_timeout
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 155, in __call_ap
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 342, in reques
    headers=headers
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 231, in GE
    query_params=query_params
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 222, in reques
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r
kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (500
Reason: Internal Server Erro
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '03bf375f-a5b3-4514-9903-a17cc3a3f886', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Tue, 26 Feb 2019 15:47:16 GMT', 'Content-Length': '322'}
HTTP response body: b'{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Get https://10.142.15.217:10250/containerLogs/default/ex-kube-templates-c87ea4f8/base?follow=true\\u0026tailLines=10: No SSH tunnels currently open. Were the targets able to accept an ssh-key for user \\"gke-9d36bbaf757434bb291e\\"?","code":500}\n
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fix - Improper Configuration

**User error!**
It was a GCP Firewall rule priority issue. We had a firewall rule blocking all traffic at a specific priority, and that priority was lower in number (a higher priority) than the default `priority 1000` assigned to Cloud Composer SSH firewall rule that lets the K8s master talk to the nodes.

Once I elevated the Cloud Composer firewall rules, it worked perfectly.